# How to package wallpapers into an apk?

Tags: android

I don't have any programming knowledge, but I have installed Eclipse, and android SDK. I want to package some wallpapers into an apk and publish them in the android market. Can someone show me a tutorial or explain how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about 'live wallpapers' or simply 'image wallpapers'

Answer (score 1):

Files placed in your res folder when you build your application are placed inside the apk.

Though they will not be avaliable for external use other than your own application. Aka, you will not be able select them via the built in wallpaper picker options.

You would have to have the apk copy the resource files to the SDCard when it is run.

Actually here is another question asking the same thing:

[How to put a wallpaper inside an apk file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717752/how-to-put-a-wallpaper-inside-an-apk-file)

Its relatively straight forward but requires some basic android and programming skills.

1. Store all your wallpapers in your res folder (apk).
2. WHen the application launches, one by one, save the resource file to the SDCard. (Check if they already exist first).
3. The user can now navigate his/her photos and see your wallpapers. - And hence able to set them as wallpapers.

Comment: Are there any tutorials how to build only a wallpaper apk pack on Eclipse?

Comment: Following my theory, this would be a wallpaper apk pack. There is no other way of doing it from what I've read. You cannot just put images into an APK as the user will not be able to access them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any programming knowledge, it doesn't matter. Here is an android wallpaper app example code, you can easily replace your image url (which should be on internet) inside.

[Android Wallpaper App Tutorial (1-4)](http://jmsliu.com/1879/android-gridview-example-in-real-wallpaper-app.html)